# How to connect into spotify

Tags: python

I was wondering how can I create a raspberry pi spotify streamer where I can stream my music to and then can control leds with the music frequency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Mopidy](https://www.mopidy.com/) with extensions allows you to stream from cloud services such as Spotify (and others as well as local files obviously). It can be run pretty well on the Raspberry Pi and can be controlled by a multitude of clients (local or remote; command line, graphical, web based). Packages for installation are available for Debian and Arch Linux, but other than that it can be installed from source and is running on python2.7.

(As for the second part: that would be best left for another question.)

**Addendum: Performance**

On my Pi2B with current Arch Linux mopidy runs at about 25..30 % CPU load while playing local .mp3 files (192k) from an USB flash drive. On a single core Pi B+ at standard clocking it runs more or less at 100% CPU load and remote control actions are delayed and might interrupt playback.

This might differ a little for spotify streaming given that it uses .ogg comression over .mp3 and depending on the selected bitrate (spotify's quality levels).